# Focus a specific row without deselecting already selected rows

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView dgv.

I have selected some set of rows.
and then right clicking on one of those rows I will show options.

Here I want the cursor focus to come the row on which I am right clicking without deselecting the selected set of rows.

I am trying this

```
dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows(hitRow).Cells(0)  'here hitRow is the row index of my clicked row
```

but this code deselecting all my selected rows and bringing the cursor focus to the clicked row.
I don't want the deselection to happen.
I tried adding this after my code

```
dgv.Rows(hitRow).Selected = True
```

but it selects only one row.

Comment: Wouldn't that clash with standard GUI CUA guidelines?

Comment: what is the inside of `hitRow`? can you share?

Comment: It is the rowIndex of the selected row.

Comment: try to in Mouse_up event.. and let me know if it happen again. :)